# NodeJS: Accessing child's static methods from parent

Tags: javascript, node.js, static

I am using ES6:

```
class Parent {
  static sayHello(){
    ChildN.sayHi()
  }
}

class ChildOne extends Parent {
  static sayHi(){
    console.log('hi from ChildOne')
  }
}

class ChildTwo extends Parent {
  static sayHi(){
    console.log('hi from ChildTwo')
  }
}

ChildOne.sayHello()
ChildTwo.sayHello()
```

I would like to have N children. Is it possible to dynamically get child class inside of parent and call its static method? In other words, how can I generalize ChildN in the parent class?

Answer (score 1):

By accessing `this` inside the parent's static method, you'll reference the child class, so just do `this.sayHi()`:

```js
class Parent {
  static sayHello(){
    this.sayHi()
  }
}

class ChildOne extends Parent {
  static sayHi(){
    console.log('hi from ChildOne')
  }
}

class ChildTwo extends Parent {
  static sayHi(){
    console.log('hi from ChildTwo')
  }
}

ChildOne.sayHello()
ChildTwo.sayHello()
```

Comment: That was quick. Thank you!

Comment: Where are static methods stored?  I'm wondering how Javascript finds a static method from `this.sayHello()`?  I didn't think they were stored on the prototype.

Comment: @jfriend00 Static methods are properties directly on the class. It's the exact same thing you can see here: https://jsfiddle.net/yostuc1f/1/ So when you call `ChildOne.sayHello()`, the calling context is `ChildOne`, so the `this` in `sayHello` on the parent class also references `ChildOne`.

Comment: @SargisPlusPlus When an answer solves your problem, you may consider marking it as Accepted (check the checkbox on the left) to indicate that the issue is resolved :)